# Using unique function to return data from an excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with the third column containing Provider Names and the sixth column containing provider states. I have been attempting to use the unique function in order to get a list of names from the third column that have either AR or AK as their states listed in the sixth column. Here is the code I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('Medicare.xlsx', skiprows=5)
df.head()
hospitals = pd.unique(df[['Provider Name']].values)
hospAR = pd.unique(df[['Provider Name', 'Provider State'='AR']])
hospAK = pd.unique(df[['Provider Name', 'Provider State'='AK']])
```

How do I fix the code so that it gives me a list of provider names who have either AR or AK in their sixth column?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data set?

Comment: I think you mean "...who have either AR or AK in their `Provider State` column?" Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant  "...list of provider names who have either AR or AK in their <s>sixth</s> `Provider State` column?", this is one possible approach to this

Generate some dummy data

```
import pandas as pd
d = [
    ['Provider Name','Provider State'],
    ['ABC','AR'],
    ['DEF','OH'],
    ['GHI','AK'],
    ['MKP','NY'],
    ['MSN','AK']
    ]
df = pd.DataFrame(d[1:], columns=d[0])

print(df)
  Provider Name Provider State
0           ABC             AR
1           DEF             OH
2           GHI             AK
3           MKP             NY
4           MSN             AK
```

Filter the `Provider State` column to find states containing either `AK` or `AR`, and then return only the `Provider Name` column (as required in the OP)

```
df_filtered = (
    df.loc[df['Provider State']
        .str
        .contains('AR|AK'),
        'Provider Name']
                )

print(df_filtered)
0    ABC
2    GHI
4    MSN
Name: Provider Name, dtype: object
```

Optionally, if you want to get the filtered `Provider Names` as a list

```
print(df_filtered.tolist())
['ABC', 'GHI', 'MSN']
```